# C#. Windows Form. Partial class problem when migration from .NET 4.6.1 to 4.6.2

Tags: c#, winforms, compilation, partial-classes, .net-4.6.2

I try to modify Target framework from **.NET 4.6.1** to **4.6.2** in Project Properties window of VS2019.

Compilation of version 4.6.1 is OK.

Compilation of version 4.6.2 fails: **error CS0101: The namespace 'CoreClient' already contains a definition for 'ClientCore'.**

I have 7 files with

```
public partial class ClienCore {}
```

All of the classes into the same namespace CoreClient.
The error message points only to one of file from them.

For test, when I rename/delete this partial class in the file to eliminate the error, the same error points to other file from these 7 after compilation.

Image below shows Properties window of the project
[image]

Comment: do you have a namespace equal to this class name ?

Comment: So is it `ClienCore` or `ClientCore`?

Comment: The namespace is 'CoreClient' , class name is 'ClientCore' . Them are different

Answer (score 1):

My colleague found solution. The problem is hidden into files

**Properties/Settings.Designer.cs**

**Properties/Resources.Designer.cs**

ClientCore/Properties/Settings.Designer.cs

old line

```
  namespace CoreClient.CoreClient.Properties {
```

new line after fix the problem

```
  namespace CoreClient.Properties {
```

ClientCore/Properties/Resources.Designer.cs

old line

```
namespace CoreClient.CoreClient.Properties {
...
...
global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("CoreClient.CoreClient.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
```

new line after fix the problem

```
namespace CoreClient.Properties {
...
...
global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("CoreClient.ClientCore.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
```